# Spring-Integration Marshallling Exception

Tags: spring-integration

While marshalling jaxb objects i am getting exception, can anyone please help ? I am not even using LinkedHashMap in my jaxb objects.

Exception thrown

com.sun.istack.internal.SAXException2: class java.util.LinkedHashMap nor any of its super class is known to this context.
**javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: class java.util.LinkedHashMap nor any of its super class is known to this context.]**
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.MarshallerImpl.write(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.MarshallerImpl.marshal(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller.marshal(Jaxb2Marshaller.java:662)
    ... 49 more
Caused by: com.sun.istack.internal.SAXException2: class java.util.LinkedHashMap nor any of its super class is known to this context.
javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: class java.util.LinkedHashMap nor any of its super class is known to this context.
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.XMLSerializer.reportError(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.XMLSerializer.reportError(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.XMLSerializer.childAsXsiType(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.property.ArrayElementProperty.serializeListBody(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.property.ArrayERProperty.serializeBody(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.ClassBeanInfoImpl.serializeBody(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.XMLSerializer.childAsSoleContent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.ClassBeanInfoImpl.serializeRoot(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.XMLSerializer.childAsRoot(Unknown Source)
    ... 52 more

Comment: This question is answered in another post i created.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24716077/need-spring-jdbc-resultset-to-return-list-of-objects-instead-of-linkedhashmap/24725484#24725484

Comment: Can you put the rest of the configurations? from this exception seems that your payload is a java.util.LinkedHashMap and Jaxb2Marshaller can't serialize this object.